# Why spreadsheet file id is changed?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have spreadsheet files that created in last year.

My application saves those files IDs to 3rd party DB system using Drive REST API every day. (Primary key is file ID)

But one day, all file IDs changed and number of records is increased more than doubled.

I thought fileId is unique and I can use it in 3rd party system as external Id or primary key, but IDs changed....

Is this Drive REST API's bug or my fault?
What should I do if I want to use file ID as exrternal ID for syncing with 3rd party system?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the problem is those ids were of "old" sheets. Google has been recently migrating old sheets to new sheets. Once migrated you cant revert it to the old one. New sheets have new ids. I complained about this last year in the issues page when the thing started to no avail. You can still use the old id and it opens the new sheet. Your only hope now is to scan all the ids, open them and see if its id changed so you upgrade it in your db.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I think it's very difficult to migrate to new IDs.

Comment: Yes it is. I dont know why google decided to make a change that breaks a lot of apps knowing that it would happen and having the alternative to keep the old ids instead.